# How to calculate Roll-off and Ripple (Stop-band/Pass-band) from a filter in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, digital-filter

I am facing difficulties in calculating Roll-off and Ripple (Stop-band/Pass-band) from a filter in MATLAB. Suppose I have an unknown vector of filter 'Filter1' which is 1x201 double.

I have plotted its Fourier transform to find out its magnitude spectrum in frequency domain. From there I can conclude that whether the filter is "lowpass or bandpass or highpass". I have also found its frequency response using `[h,w] = freqz(hfilt)`.

But I am not able to find out Roll-off and Ripple (Stop-band/Pass-band). Would anybody please help me with proper reading materials or right directions?

Comment: Have a look at [`measure`](http://mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/measure.html) or [`fvtool`](http://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fvtool.html)

Comment: The freqz(hfilt) function already uses fvtool for plotting magnitude and phase of the filter in the normalized frequency. And I am not sure how to use measure() function because I don't have the coefficients of filter. I only have the vector of filter 'Filter1' which is 1x201 double.